# Yet another sequence with letters and a question mark

Tags: sequence

A quick one.

What is the next element of this sequence?

```
v, u, s, p, l, g, a, Z, R, I, ?
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The next element of the sequence is

> 4

Because

> each element has an ASCII code that is less than the previous by one more than the previous was less than its previous...

The trick is

> the question mark is part of the sequence.

Comment: Was just typing it up, well done.

Comment: @hexomino thanks, sometimes the hardest part is finding the words to explain.

Comment: I knew it would be fast.  Solved after just 8 views.  It was more like a 100m spring.  Congratulation to both.

Comment: “I don't know half of you half as well as I should like; and I like less than half of you half as well as you deserve.”

Answer (score 0):

para este problema hice un script en tcl, que devuelve el codigo ascii de cada letra u simbolo dado.
v u s p l g a

que convierte cada letra en su numero ascii, y vi que la secuencia numerica es asi:

## v,  118

## u,  117

## s,  115

## p,  112

## l,  108

## g,  103

103 -6 = 97

## a,  97

97 -7 = 90

## Z,  90

90 -8 = 82

## R,  82

82 -9 = 73

## I,  73

73 -10 = 63

## ?,  63

63 -11 = 52
el codigo ascii para 52 es 4

=> deberia seguir el "4" porque su ascii es el 52

Comment: This is correct, but it doesn't add anything to the answer already given.

Comment: many times we have the correct answer but we need a second opinion to confirm that the answer is correct.

Comment: @FlorianF Also, it's in Spanish, so it does add something: accessibility